# Formula problem for Calculated column to display 1 or 0 based upon Yes/NO column

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am attempting to create KPI's for a column named "Template Received" (YES/NO drop down selection) based upon a Calculated Column that either turns the YES into "1" or the NO into "0".  I am having trouble because my calculated column is showing all NO's and no numbers what so ever.  Please assist in showing me what it is i am doing wrong! (SharePoint 2013)

=IF([Template Received]=TRUE,"1",IF([Template Received]=FALSE,"0"))

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you created a "Choice (menu to choose from)" field instead of "Yes/No (check box)". So you have to compare the actual value and not TRUE or FALSE.

This should work if Template Received is a Choice field with YES and NO as drop down options.

=IF([Template Received]="YES",1,0)

Comment: Yes... correct It was a choice menu.  And thank you very much... that worked perfectly!